# Why does fetchColumn() return 1 when there are 2 columns?

Tags: php, sql, pdo, prepared-statement

Why does `fetchColumn()` return "1" when there are actually two columns in the database matching these criteria ?

If there is 1 record in the database matching it will return false?
(I used to do `$num_of_rows = $stmt->num_rows()` which worked perfectly)

```
$follower = 1;
$following = 1;

$stmt = $dbCon->prepare(" SELECT login_followers_status "
        . " FROM login_followers "
        . " WHERE login_followers_follower = ? "
        . " AND login_followers_following = ? ");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $follower);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $following);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch();
$status = $row['login_followers_status'];
$num_of_rows = $stmt->fetchColumn();

echo $num_of_rows;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you do not read the manual?

[public mixed PDOStatement::fetchColumn ([ int $column_number = 0 ] )](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php)

> PDOStatement::fetchColumn — Returns a single column from the next row
>   of a result set.
>
> Returns a single column from the next row of a result set or FALSE if
>   there are no more rows.
>
> **Warning** There is no way to return another column from the same row if
>   you use PDOStatement::fetchColumn() to retrieve data.